# ES2015 - updating filtered items in a collection and combining updating the previous collection

Tags: functional-programming, ecmascript-6

So say i have a collection:

```
const collection = [0,3,2,4];

var r = collection.filter((item) => {
    return item > 2;
}).map((item) => {
    return item + 2;
});
// I could just `.map()` them back in but that seems ineffective

console.log(r); // 5,6
```

Is there a functional (fp) way to compose this code to update my previous collection to get the expected result (given the index of the result is important) ?

e.g. expected result: [0,5,2,6]

Comment: What do you mean by "update my previous collection"? Data is immutable in functional programming.

Comment: Sorry, i meant create a new collection with it the modified items contained with the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var r = collection.map(item => item > 2 ? item + 2 : item)
```

instead?

I.e. `.map` all items but only modify the ones that match your condition.